# I tried all possible combinations to pass test cases but no success. I passed only one test case i.e. sample one

Tags: java

Tyson is all prepared for the Beyblade World Championship. The tournament is team-based and each team can have N members. A player can fight against a single player only. Team G-Revolution is all excited and pumped up as they have practised a lot. Kenny, the mind of team G-Revolution, has created a database where he has the data about the power of other teams’ members and his own team members. The tournament is going to start in some time and Kenny moves to the cafeteria to have a snack before the competition.

The team G-Revolution is to fight in some time and they are tensed up as someone has kidnapped Kenny from the cafeteria. They have made a police complaint and the police are searching for Kenny. Luckily, they have found his device with all the data. The problem is, the data is present randomly and not in the order they have to fight the opponent. Team G-Revolution wants to win at any cost and for that, they need the order in which they have to fight optimally to win the maximum number of battles.

A player can win only when his/her beyblade power is strictly greater than the opponents beyblade power.

**Example:**
Consider the team size is 3, N = 3
The 3 players of both the teams are shown with their beyblade powers.
Team G-Revolution is presented in the order: Tyson, Max, Ray
Team All Starz is presented in the order: Michael, Eddy, Steve
With the given arrangement, Team G-Revolution would be able to win only 1 fight. Team G-Revolution should be shuffled in an optimal manner as below:

The maximum number of fights Team G-Revolution can win is 2 when they are arranged optimally or fight in an optimal order.

Team G-Revolution needs help with the device. Tyson has heard about your skills and called you up to help them shuffle their positions in an order such that they would be able to win the maximum number of fights. Can you help Tyson and Team G-Revolution?

Input Format
The first line of input consists of the number of test cases, T

The first line of each test case consists of the number of members each team can have, N.

The second line of each test case consists of N space-separated integers representing the power of beyblades of Team G-Revolution members.

The third line of each test case consists of N space-separated integers representing the power of beyblades of opponent team members.

```
Constraints
1<= T <=100000
1<= N <=100000
0<= Power of Beyblade <= LLONG_MAX
```

Output Format
For each test case, print the maximum number of fights Team G-Revolution can win if they go to fight in an optimal manner.

**Sample TestCase 1**

```
Input
1
10
3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1 
2 7 0 9 3 6 0 6 2 6 
Output
7
```

**Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CandidateCode {
    private static int testCase = 0;
    private static int numOfMembers = 0;
    private static int gRevolutionTeamSize = 0;
    private static int opponentTeamSize = 0;
    private static int numOfGRevolutionWins = 0;
    private static final Integer initial_Index = 0;
    private static final Integer second_Index = 1;
    private static final Integer third_Index = 2;
    private static final Integer fourth_Index = 3;
    private static final Integer noOfIndex = 4;
    private static final Integer testNumber = 100000;
    private static String[] powerOpponentTeamArr = null;
    private static String[] powerGRevolutionTeamArr = null;

    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        List<Integer> gRevolutionWinsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] input = new String[noOfIndex];
        try{
            for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
                input[i] = scan.nextLine();
            }
            if (!validateInput(input[initial_Index],input[second_Index])) {
                System.exit(initial_Index);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
        }
        finally{
            scan.close();
        }

        testCase = Integer.parseInt(input[initial_Index]);

        numOfMembers = Integer.parseInt(input[second_Index]);

        String gRevolutionMembers = input[third_Index];
        powerGRevolutionTeamArr = gRevolutionMembers.split(" ");

        String opponentMembers = input[fourth_Index];
        powerOpponentTeamArr = opponentMembers.split(" ");

        gRevolutionTeamSize = powerGRevolutionTeamArr.length;
        long[] totalGRevolutionTeamArr = new long[gRevolutionTeamSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < gRevolutionTeamSize; i++){
            totalGRevolutionTeamArr[i] = Long.parseLong(powerGRevolutionTeamArr[i]);
            validateInputPower(totalGRevolutionTeamArr[i]);
        }

        opponentTeamSize = powerOpponentTeamArr.length;
        long[] totalOpponentTeamArr = new long[opponentTeamSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < opponentTeamSize; i++){
            totalOpponentTeamArr[i] = Long.parseLong(powerOpponentTeamArr[i]);
            validateInputPower(totalOpponentTeamArr[i]);
        }

        Arrays.sort(totalGRevolutionTeamArr);
        Arrays.sort(totalOpponentTeamArr);

        for(int i = 0; i < numOfMembers; i++){
            if((totalGRevolutionTeamArr[i] - totalOpponentTeamArr[i]) > 0){
                numOfGRevolutionWins = numOfGRevolutionWins + 1;
            }
        }

        int numCount = numOfGRevolutionWins;
        int moveMembers = numOfMembers - numCount - 1;
        if(moveMembers >= 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < moveMembers; i++){
                long teamMember = totalOpponentTeamArr[numCount];
                int j;
                int numOfGRevolutionWins_1 = 0;
                for (j = 0; j < moveMembers; j++){
                    totalOpponentTeamArr[numCount + j] = totalOpponentTeamArr[numCount + j + 1];
                }
                totalOpponentTeamArr[numCount + j] = teamMember;


                for(int k = numCount; k < numOfMembers; k++){
                    if((totalGRevolutionTeamArr[k] - totalOpponentTeamArr[k]) > 0){
                        numOfGRevolutionWins_1 = numOfGRevolutionWins_1 + 1;
                    }
                }
                gRevolutionWinsList.add(numOfGRevolutionWins_1);
            }
        numOfGRevolutionWins = numOfGRevolutionWins + Collections.max(gRevolutionWinsList);
        }

        System.out.println(numOfGRevolutionWins);
   }

    private static boolean validateInput(String testCases, String noOfPlayers) {
        int test1 = Integer.parseInt(testCases);
        int numOfPlayers = Integer.parseInt(noOfPlayers);
        if (second_Index <= test1 && test1 <= testNumber && second_Index <= numOfPlayers && numOfPlayers <= testNumber) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static void validateInputPower(long memberPower) {
        if (!(initial_Index <= memberPower && memberPower <= Long.MAX_VALUE)) {
            System.exit(initial_Index);
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Input from line 1 = 1
Input from line 2 = 10
Input from line 3 = 3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1
Input from line 4 = 2 7 0 9 3 6 0 6 2 6
Scanner input job succeeded if we see some value here = 1
Finally block is called to free Scanner job
Value from first line and parsed string to int = 1
Value from second line and parsed string to int = 10
Value from third line = 3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1
Value from fourth line = 2 7 0 9 3 6 0 6 2 6
Parsed string number 1 to long : 3
Parsed string number 2 to long : 6
Parsed string number 3 to long : 7
Parsed string number 4 to long : 5
Parsed string number 5 to long : 3
Parsed string number 6 to long : 5
Parsed string number 7 to long : 6
Parsed string number 8 to long : 2
Parsed string number 9 to long : 9
Parsed string number 10 to long : 1
Parsed string number 1 to long : 2
Parsed string number 2 to long : 7
Parsed string number 3 to long : 0
Parsed string number 4 to long : 9
Parsed string number 5 to long : 3
Parsed string number 6 to long : 6
Parsed string number 7 to long : 0
Parsed string number 8 to long : 6
Parsed string number 9 to long : 2
Parsed string number 10 to long : 6
After sorting number 1 is : 1
After sorting number 2 is : 2
After sorting number 3 is : 3
After sorting number 4 is : 3
After sorting number 5 is : 5
After sorting number 6 is : 5
After sorting number 7 is : 6
After sorting number 8 is : 6
After sorting number 9 is : 7
After sorting number 10 is : 9
After sorting number 1 is : 0
After sorting number 2 is : 0
After sorting number 3 is : 2
After sorting number 4 is : 2
After sorting number 5 is : 3
After sorting number 6 is : 6
After sorting number 7 is : 6
After sorting number 8 is : 6
After sorting number 9 is : 7
After sorting number 10 is : 9
Number of G-Revolution wins are : 5
Number will be used is : 4
Number shifted is : 6
Number of wins afterwards : 1
Number shifted is : 6
Number of wins afterwards : 2
Number shifted is : 6
Number of wins afterwards : 2
Number shifted is : 7
Number of wins afterwards : 2
Number of wins afterwards in list : [1, 2, 2, 2]
Answer is = 7
```

Answer (score 3):

You have fallen into the classic trap of constructing an algorithm based on the example rather than considering the general case.   This is not a criticism, but something that we all have to be aware of in order to fight against.

Take a look at your loop here :

```
           for (j = 0; j < moveMembers; j++){
                totalOpponentTeamArr[numCount + j] = totalOpponentTeamArr[numCount + j + 1];
            }
            totalOpponentTeamArr[numCount + j] = teamMember;
```

So in the given example, a straight sort results in us winning the first numCount = 5 matches, so your algorithm looks to leave those 5 results and rearrange our team from position 6.

Trouble is, that's only for the supplied example.

Consider if the opposing team didn't have strengths 0 or 1, but replaced those with 3  - that is, their team was : 3 3 3 3 3 6 6 6 7 9.

In that case, on the initial straight-sorted matchups, we would lose the first 4 and only win 1 match (the 5-3).

Consider how your algorithm would behave in that scenario, rearranging the team after numCount = 1 ?

So a better algorithm would be :

1) Sort each team as you do at present

2) Starting with their weakest member, find our weakest member that would beat them

3) Continue with their next weakest member, finding our weakest member who would beat that one

etc

At each step, if we have to skip over one of our members, make a note of them (in a list or something).  When we come come to the point that we run out of members to match against one of theirs, then just fill in the rest of the matches with this list of our skipped-over members - after all, they were never going to win a match anyway !

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of test cases T here.
Input Format The first line of input consists of the number of test cases, T
1<= T <=100000

Can you please help me to understand this.

Comment: T is just the number in the first line of the file, and they are telling you it will be between 1 and 100000 (so you don’t have to check for negative numbers, etc), so the file will have (1 + 3*T) lines - for example the sample file they supplied had T being 1.  If instead T was 5 for example, then the file would have 16 lines - the first line being that 5, followed by 5 sets of three lines, each of those sets being a test case of the teams.  Naturally, your program (without the debugging println statements) will output T lines.

Comment: Thanks Racraman, it really helped me. I am done with my logic and iteration for various test cases, 100% successful for all TEST CASES!

Comment: Way to go :)   Congratulations !

Answer (score 1):

```
t=int(input())
while t>0:
    n=int(input())
    gr=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
    op=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
    gr.sort()
    op.sort()
    l=r=count=0
    while l<n and r<n:
        if gr[l]>op[r]:
            l+=1
            r+=1
            count+=1
        elif gr[l]<=op[r]:
            l+=1
    print(count)
    t-=1
```

Comment: Can you explain your logic

Comment: After sorting, keep comparing if you can beat the opponent , if condition satisfies, increment the team pointer and the opponent pointer.  If not beatable by the current team mate, increment the "team pointer only" so that you can compare the current opponent with the nxt team mate.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I also appear for the same contest and I got full marks.
Might my code be helpful for you.
to solve this you can sort both the list to reverse order and compare each other. Refer below a working example of in Python:

```
    def main():
    testCase=int(input())
    while testCase>0:
    count=0
    numberOfPlayer=int(input())
    firstPlayer=list(map(int,input().split()))
    secondPlayer=list(map(int,input().split()))
    firstPlayer.sort(reverse=True)
    secondPlayer.sort(reverse=True)
    p=0
    for i in range(numberOfPlayer):
        for j in range(p,numberOfPlayer):
            if firstPlayer[i]>secondPlayer[j]:
                p=j+1
                count+=1
                break
    print(count)
    testCase-=1
main() 
# Made by Ankur Patel
```

For java based solution 
[refer](https://dohere.blogspot.com/2020/06/techgig-code-gladiators-2020-solutions_10.html)

Answer (score 0):

**My logic:**

```
// Logic for comparing team battles in optimum manner
        while(gRev < numOfMembers){
            if((totalGRevolutionTeamArr[gRev] - totalOpponentTeamArr[opp]) > 0){
                gRev++;
                opp++;
                numOfWins++;
            }
            else{
                gRev++;
            }
        }
```